# How to automate removal of database replication if forest connect by name is false?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have master and foreign ML cluster **coupled** and databases replication enabled for few databases. I'd like to automate the removal of database replications and then re-add db replications with `connect by forest name` set to false and still be able to do it via script. I'd like to avoid doing this activity from GUI

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done via the Manage API - http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/management/databases . A call to http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties allows you to modify the properties of a database - this comment in the page - "Database-level replication can be changed with the database-replication properties of the database. Specify foreign-replica(s) on the replica database(s) and foreign-master on the master database." indicates where to start.

When using the Manage API, I find it very helpful to go to host:8002/manage/v2 and then find the resource(s) you're looking to modify, and then click on "properties" to see what how they're configured. Then, you can use an HTTP client like curl, or a Java library like https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-app-deployer to make the calls to the Manage API.